# Typing based on subsets of unions in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, algebraic-data-types, typescript4.0

I am working on a TypeScript library ([here it is](https://github.com/korkje/adt/tree/8e443bc)) for algebraic data types (or whatever one wishes to call them), and am struggling with some of the more intricate typing.

The algebraic data types work like this:

```js
// Create ADT instantiator
const value_adt = adt({
    num: (value: number) => value,
    str: (value: string) => value,
    obj: (value: object) => value,
});

// Extract union of variants
type ValueADT = Variants<typeof value_adt>;

// 'ValueADT' will be typed as:
// { [tag]: "num", value: number } |
// { [tag]: "str", value: string } |
// { [tag]: "obj", value: object }

// Create instance of 'value_adt'
const my_value = value_adt.str("hello") as ValueADT;
```

And I have created a `match` function (yes, this is very much inspired by Rust) for matching, and extracting associated data from the matched variant, that works like this:

```js
match(my_value, {
    num: value => console.log(`number: ${value}`);
    str: value => console.log(`string: ${value}`);
    obj: value => console.log(`object: ${value}`);
});
```

The parameter typing for the provided matchers work like a charm. However, I have added the option to omit one or more matchers and replace them with a default case:

```js
match(my_value, {
    num: value => console.log(`number: ${value}`);
    [def]: value => console.log(`not number: ${value}`);
});
```

I have managed to type the default matcher's parameter as the union of all the variants' value types (`ValueADT["value"]` in this case), but that only really makes sense if all matchers are omitted and replaced with the default matcher.

I would very much like to be able to type the value parameter of the default matcher based on which other matchers are provided, e.g. it should be `string | object` in the above example, not `number | string | object`., so my question is what (if any) advanced TypeScript sorcery is available to achieve something like that?

[Here](https://github.com/korkje/adt/blob/8e443bca37f5ece3acb35201a6da878d7d61c586/src/lib/match.ts) is the link to the `matcher` source code and types as is.

Note:
I am not sure about this question's title, suggestions are welcome.

Update:
Here is some self-contained code that illustrates the undesired behavior, i.e. that the default matcher's parameter type is a union that contains `number`, which it logically cannot be:

```js
type Variant<T, U> = { tag: T, value: U };

const adt = { tag: "num", value: 1 } as
    | Variant<"num", number>
    | Variant<"str", string>
    | Variant<"obj", object>;

type MatchAll<T extends Variant<string, any>> = {
    [K in T["tag"]]: T extends Variant<K, infer V>
        ? (value: V) => any
        : never
};

const def = Symbol("[def]ault matcher");

type Matchers<T extends Variant<string, any>> =
    | MatchAll<T>
    | Partial<MatchAll<T>> & {
        [def]: (value: T["value"]) => any;
    };

function match<
    T extends Variant<string, any>,
    U extends Matchers<T>,
>(
    variant: T,
    matchers: U,
) {
    const matcher = matchers[variant.tag as keyof U];

    if (matcher === undefined) {
        throw new Error(`No match for '${variant.tag}'!`);
    }

    matcher(variant.value);
}

match(adt, {
    num: value => console.log(`number: ${value}`),
    [def]: value => console.log(`not number: ${value}`),
});
```

...and a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZwHbADwBUA0UCqAfFALxQDeUwcA5gFxS5QBucANgK4QP5QC+AbgBQQgMYB7VAGdgUOABNZZStXpQARKg4BbdXladuUAIz85UoVCtQAPrEQp0GTTr1Qt2gEYQEhS9bt4ZDRMdRkEN3CkVBo-a1t7YKd1cU8AKzdUtIhRYEJhIVBIKABZOGBRAAsAQTY2bCgIAA9gCFR5KUTHTCiYvDQQQmJlfysAbQBpKGjGMfVVdQBdRYYsRpa2jq6QjAm8aIAzH1g4+OsAfigACgMuBhgASlJiAdGzhlQIZh8hQREJaSyeQQA6kKAAZRAXnEbCu6jGwIOizgHDYsm05SqPnUDwKRWgZQqlR8UgazVa7U6QW6GF6NH6qEGwzedkJVVq9SwpysdgACohgCh6myanVsEMoAAyChveIIkEra63IxYObKpZPEgvRnCeJ-IQHDioXJISRQDFEjBvNbkzZUhw7OkMwY4N68W2U0qY4kIUlc12EK5vVhJYCrV3xC1Y308V1PchvAEyc3e45kKM+qRjEPdAB0qnMUAA1hAQOJQfhFgV4khQVcM2mSGQjYjohB5PHZdZgJUEOIAO7uCCDgCiCD7CCuAAMAHLiFNEqAHcQIKAAcgAJOQcyF87Q+GuAIRT3FvPgiSOpyc79C55Wn89CDNXBTAPAJ+IeBjK55QJMwiBczYcQaGnDxvAQBgt2VPgTwjax5SRb92C4X9-zYQDgNAqdUHEWRwJ8KDtxQiBYIeV0+FxIA) link.

Update 2:
After this was answered, I managed to also correctly infer the return type of `match` (it returns the returned value from the called matcher). This is a bit of an aside with respect to what I asked here, but it might be interesting for anyone who comes across this in the future: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCGBzGBeGAiA+phjvoG4AoIqATwAcBTGANXgCcBLeMKAHgBUAaGAVQB8qGAG8YAbVwBdAFwweMAG7wANgFcqcvjAC+xIqEiwAJlQBmwgMpkAtgCMQKgBTpxps1PhqVsG-CjAABZUDOgAlPrk1DAAsv5BAGIgDFwwVAAeUFRgxhB0jCxs7NDMYIi8rGQCvADSaZnZuTAACgwg1AzkNVRVwiJEMIMSmHVMYDA1sjBOyuqaMACimQzwwBwKYpJIUyO6AuLosxroUmGoQpXEeiRRNHEBwQwQqRlZOXn0zKwcJWPlMJVqhN6m8mq12iEuj0hCgBkMlsB1KYuJJKFQQBZpLUhK9GnkwFRFCE4YMAPzTe6JZJcbFhEkwOROSmBJIpBQ1IQAMlE9KGEncUxmqg0cgRSKoNNEEmkcjqOn2h2FVBOZxQFzAZGIfJ0ERuaNi8UCAEEVCoXg13vkvkVfmUKhqBDCDQ8Qs8FJxUdQMXBtgJIvqAPJqDgxWogvEwW2IJ1itTImq8ADWPW9MRxFqaBKJDHp5Ji4ct-T5fPEuzGE0FR3mlVVQjGZhCMAASlqhjoYOSmwyYFniXy5PncYXeUNxMmyHIozAAD6R2wOFSVpVyGvnGD1xst+ntzvd3sMfRmNRgNZMcAwPwPdj0zgFpqfQo-KClf6A7j0upDsFtDpQsjvvlBwzPJmVdSUOXfAQnHpZRrSgOQeHpS8gldAcZ2dFCnnAgRZ2ZE0zU4AQiDCOQgxDXgPVub1pD9EgjxPKAz3GZDAmvPlby-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-mdb1w7Rb5aWlCl+HA+1hXQ6V9KPFVoR2sTqZZfl3Xhfjg3dRJ9zTbMc3YH63qrfFq2ARyGAbf8u3KbCmnMAAJjdh4PZOr2+R97neYz4Ps6MBOBWT9W05jzOQ6H3OjYLs3vBLgbVBUe3Q8d2mAGY26CDuWZ5EsR8jv3x61yfB+gd9DZIUn8JgABqGB3GL1eqabgAWbfAl3ruhh7v2+6DnHae4do5HxThHfuQCL70k1r7FOmtIFZ31gfDKo9U6H0QVPaBV984wBAO0f6Dsm4AFZP7f33r-AOYD1YANjkgnOICJbUM6qAzB59RaGxgKTEIrVJokFwfgighC15NwAGxkM9hQ9mVC4E0KoWw5BQwI6yJYUwhRDChj40QGghBgD6HT04dwlqyRJpAA).

Comment: @jcalz Updated with code and playground link.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgAdym) meet your needs? Getting the proper inference around that extra symbol-keyed property is tough to get right, but the general idea here is that the function should be generic in the matcher keys.  If that works for you I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Brilliant, that looks like it fits my needs, yes! One thing I noticed is that if all "normal" matchers are present, the default matcher is still "allowed", and it's parameter type becomes `any`, not `never`. Anyway, this looks very good to me, thanks a lot.

Comment: You could switch the order of the overloads to get the `never` inference instead of `any`.  I will write up an answer when I get the chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what follows I am concerned only with the typings, and only from the point of view of the *callers* of `match()`; the implementation may need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like to prevent compiler errors, since complicated generic call signatures tend to be hard to verify.

---

My inclination here would be to [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) `match()` so that the fully exhaustive "match all" case is handled separately from the matchers-with-default "partial" case.

For the "partial" case, we want `match()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) not only in `T`, the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) type of the `variant` argument, but also in `K`, the keys of the `matchers` argument.  And we might as well make `Matchers` generic in both `T` and `K` too, so that we can represent the argument type for all the methods as precisely as possible.

---

So here is a possible definition of `Matchers<T, K>`:

```
type Matchers<T extends Variant<string, any>, K extends PropertyKey> = {
    [P in K]: (value: P extends typeof def ?
        Exclude<T, { tag: Exclude<K, typeof def> }>["value"] :
        Extract<T, { tag: P }>["value"]
    ) => any };
```

The idea is that we [map](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over each element `P` of `K` to get callbacks returning `any`.  To find the `value` parameter type of the callback with key `P`: if `P` is the type of `def`, then `value` corresponds to all the variants not mentioned in `K` (which we build using [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)).  Otherwise, we assume `P` is one of the tags from `T`, in which case `value` corresponds to the value for the variant with that tag (which we build using [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union)).

Note that if `K` happens to be the full union of `T["tag"]`, then the `[def]` callback would have a `value` argument of type `never`.  This is maybe a little strange, but probably harmless.  If it really matters, you could change this type so that the whole property is of type `never` instead of just the callback argument.

---

And here are our overloaded call signatures:

```
declare function match<T extends Variant<string, any>, K extends T["tag"] | typeof def>(
    variant: T, matchers: Matchers<T, K | typeof def>
): void;

declare function match<T extends Variant<string, any>>(
    variant: T, matchers: Matchers<T, T["tag"]>
): void;
```

The first signature handles the "partial" case with the `def` property.  The inference is a little tricky here; I found that I needed to specify `| typeof def` both in the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) for `K`, and inside the second argument to `Matchers`.  Otherwise the compiler would tend to "give up" on inferring `K` from the actual keys of the `matchers` argument.

The second signature handles the "match all" case without the `def` property, and does not need to be generic in `K` (since it will always be just the full `T["tag"]` union).

---

Let's test it against:

```
declare const adt:
    | Variant<"num", number>
    | Variant<"str", string>
    | Variant<"dat", Date>;
```

First, let's try the "match all" case:

```
match(adt, {
    num: v => v.toFixed(),
    dat: v => v.toISOString(),
    str: v => v.toUpperCase()
});
```

Looks good. The compiler knows the types of `v` in each callback.  Now let's leave out the `str` key, and add in the `[def]` key:

```
match(adt, {
    num: v => v.toFixed(),
    dat: v => v.toISOString(),
    [def]: v => v.toUpperCase()
});
```

Also looks good; the compiler knows that `v` has to be `string` in the default matcher.  Now let's leave out the `dat` key as well:

```
match(adt, {
    num: v => v.toFixed(),
    [def]: v => typeof v === "object" ? v.toISOString() :
        v.toUpperCase()
});
```

Still good; the type of `v` is now `Date | string`.  And finally let's have only the default matcher:

```
match(adt, {
    [def]: v => typeof v === "number" ? v.toFixed() :
        typeof v === "object" ? v.toISOString() :
            v.toUpperCase()
})
```

The type of `v` is the full `number | Date | string` union.  Okay now let's try including all the tags *and* the default matcher:

```
const assertNever = (x: never): never => { throw new Error("Uh oh") };

match(adt, {
    num: v => v.toFixed(),
    dat: v => v.toISOString(),
    str: v => v.toUpperCase(),
    [def]: v => assertNever(v)
});
```

That is also good, I guess.  The default matcher is accepted, and `v` is of type `never` (since we never expect the default matcher to be called).

Let's make mistakes and see what it says.  If we leave out `str` and the default matcher, we get an error:

```
match(adt, {
    num: v => v.toFixed(),
    dat: v => v.toISOString(),
}); // error!
// No overload matches this call.
// Overload 1: Property '[def]' is missing
// Overload 2: Property 'str' is missing
```

The error describes how we've failed to properly call either of the two call signatures, and that either `[def]` or `str` is missing.  If we misspell one of the keys:

```
// oops
match(adt, {
    num: v => v.toFixed(),
    dat: v => v.toISOString(),
    strr: v => v.toUpperCase(), // error, 
    //strr does not exist, Did you mean to write 'str'?
})
```

The error describes how it doesn't expect to see that misspelled key, and (depending on how close our spelling is) suggests the fix.

---

So there you go, by adding a second call signature which is generic in the matcher keys, we can get the sort of inference for the default callback argument you're looking for.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAaghgJwJZwHbADwBUA0UCqAfFALxQDeUwcA5gFxS5QBucANgK4QP5QC+AbgBQQgMYB7VAGdgUACYQAZqSgBlEAFsARuLYAKAEQBtBYoC6cDm1ka4wUQAsICAwEphQ0JCgBZO4+cpbCgIAA9gCFQ5KVhEFHQMGWRUGjw0EEI8AGkQ8MjoqAAFBHFIBFAsiAyVciEoeqgjQqgkVCgsswY9Vk5uItyIqJivCHFlUygAfjqG2YBRUNFOBWw8Smp6KAWljhWsvBGx+SViPkIjAx6uAzMoOhnZ+oXgBDhRTCZ12gZms4uriA3B5QVykYjpfgeIQKJaIaCKDiod5ISRQWz2BzBMKDArwZBoTBJVqpKDpTLtAb5GJYC4bG5QAA+VHAo3GJz0wNY+PQDCY6ICCCkDD8GMCqwpTMObMUhCErgYzHESDkHhhbDhUARSOAKLa-MxWEpQ1i3MJL2JaVQGUIHNmXPiwF5eH1gWF-icgvFNIMdLMsvlLCVKpE0IgsIQ0Ak0lkcDkjuBTLxDowBlQHA0Bjwae0zlls0TcQJKaSmagRJSeYaBdNKbkdlLABE7BBCB4APRtqAAQTYbCE+r0seAa2B2YVYJYADpgOIAGJIUIQOR6Vw4YF1x0sCfMafiACSqgA8qpzSkV2vZklxyRiDuZ-gwGUAMJwKQQFdCPjuEQdqCocSyOWND9u6g5xiOsxjluN5TjO86Lsuq7rnY163ruB7HqeNDnsCJhKJ00Fofej7OC+b4fl+7adv+gFYVA4gIPIzYgRiYHDhQo7pqhsFzguS44bMeHmNxUrQSQZAGOIWgAFZhsABhTDxGEnsk2GgvcjwNHe4gPs+r7vq4n7fkIv40Q4xJQCxjhsRBDRCQRzATqJjniRJ2ZaM4CmTDx8H8epwKzM5pDiVAkkyXJXlKUeKnEiudwBZpPG6aR+kUYZYiSDIpJSG+5QAHIQMwzgqHooQMKghXOAGFVFYxMHrA4JQAO5-hALVzAgJQIIY+AOPRDhuJCP6dj2bAtEiywWaYljWHgTXmY4LQxEcIytbVVkODZHGQVxhE+XxiEXg0G7cdpylYQJDRXnt2nJQgZEGUd9T2dxr65cABW1d0hmUSGv7iKUUgbVttQ7Rop27r5h3IZuLlEfu0UXUhlFQL+zhdQAhCZnZ5eI9G1Ww4ixmi7oQMM5kxKI7BsJO2NQIeBNE3IUAAIw-CUZSgFAADk9nc0taJIDlxJ0wzziE8TABM7OlM4XPc0k-NC4LwspMN9GA8DQ62fUUFw-tCGXfUJ03ehiOqUbZYvAgEPEXp5GrqjnbowxeBJIxcjiGTf4AbkQvsQ2ypQCA4gcGiEBoFQeNNcgEQ84r0xfkAA)

Comment: Very well explained, this is super helpful! As an aside, the `match` function in my library also returns the return value of the called matcher. With my previous solution, I had the return type typed correctly as the union of the return types of all provided matchers, but I can't seem to figure out how I would go about that with this solution.